# C++ ncurses: printw with special characters yeilds '�~T~B'

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to [print box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) with ncurses in C++, as shown below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    addstr("│");
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

When I use `printw` or `addstr` to print non-alphabetic/numeric to the screen, it only prints `�~T~B`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please give a full example of your problem

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot  - yup, setlocale did it for me